# How can I insert rows into a table based on values in two other tables with no overlaps?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After struggling with this and researching half of my work day, I'm finally giving up and asking for help. I have three tables. I need to insert into table 1, all of the information in table 2, for EACH value of table 3.

Maybe I'm just failing to wrap my head around what I need to do to accomplish this - But table 2 and table 3 have no overlapping columns, so how do I link them to insert them into table 1?

I've tried a couple of different variations, my latest is this one:

```
insert into Table1 (column1, column2, column4, column3)
    select column1, column2, column3
    from Table2
    union
    select column3
    from Table3
```

I get this error:

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

There's an additional column that I need to fill in, but since it's a blanket value, it can be done after the fact with an update statement.

***Update***

I was asked for what sort of result I'm looking for...

First number being the table it comes from, second being the column, third being the value.

**Table1**

```
2.1.1 | 2.2.1 | 3.3.1 | 2.4.1  
2.1.2 | 2.2.2 | 3.3.1 | 2.4.2  
2.1.3 | 2.2.3 | 3.3.1 | 2.4.3  
2.1.1 | 2.2.1 | 3.3.2 | 2.4.1  
2.1.2 | 2.2.2 | 3.3.2 | 2.4.2  
2.1.3 | 2.2.3 | 3.3.2 | 2.4.3
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result? I understand that you want to do this: insert into A, everything from B that corresponds to a value in C. Do you mean that values from a column in B need to exist in a column in C?

Answer (score 3):

Make `null` when column not exists :

```
select column1, column2, column3
from Table2
union all
select column3, null, null
from Table3
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to insert into table 1, all of the information in table 2, for EACH value of table 3.

I think you want a `cross join`:

```
insert into Table1 (column1, column2, column4, column3)
    select t2.column1, t2.column2, t2.column3, t1.column3
    from Table2 t2 cross join
         Table3 t3;
```